# Can I use greater than in R hist() function?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R language, and I've been playing around with some data from Google Play applications, like the number of installs, prices, number of reviews, ratings ...etc

However, I'm now trying to use `hist()` function for the "Price" column. I have 10841 records in my dataset, and the majority of these apps (around 10,000 of the 10841 apps) are free ($0.00).

Now I'm trying to find the apps that have a price higher than $0.01 and go all the way to $400.00

I tried playing with the code and changing the breaks and `xlim` and `ylim` and everything, but I can't seem to find a way to only display results larger than 0.01!

> hist(play$Price, breaks=100, xlab="Price", ylab="No. of Apps",
>   ylim=c(0, 13000), xlim=c(0.01, 100.00), main="Prices")

This is the code that I'm trying to use. I have a LOT of different alterations to the code, but none of them work!

so hopefully you can help me to find a way to do this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to try selecting only the values you are interested in from your `Price` data. `hist(play$Price[play$Price > 0.01 & play$Price < 400], ...)`

Comment: The problem with `xlim = c(0.01, 100.00)` is that this only changes the _displayed_ x limits. This is applied to the histogram _after_ the bins are calculated, i.e., the histogram that gets computed will still include the `Price = 0` data.

Comment: THANK YOU @bdemarest !! this actually did it ! i got the results i wanted and was even able to display more detailed results by playing with the ylim, xlim, and breaks.

Comment: yeah i was playing with the min and max in the xlim and i noticed that the histogram is moving but the displayed results are the same. but thanks for rhis info, great help!